# IOS: can't open Apple's Mail app with URL

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I am trying to open Apple's Mail app from my application and I am running this code:

```
   let mailURL = URL(string: "message://")!
   if UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(mailURL) {
       UIApplication.shared.open(mailURL, options: [:], completionHandler: nil)
   }
```

However, `UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(mailURL)` line returns false. This code actually working well on my other application but not working on this. Do you have any ideas what is the reason for this issue?

edit: I tried to run this both in the simulator and real device.

edit: using Xcode 12.5.1, Big Sur 11.6

Comment: What is the execution environment? Simulator? Device?

Comment: @esqew tried both

Comment: Apparently you have to add `mailto` or `message` to the `LSApplicationQueriesSchemes` to make it work.

Comment: @esqew makes sense I will try and write back if it works

Answer (score 0):

Use `mailto` for the URL’s protocol, not `message`.

Example:

```
mailto://me@example.com
```

Comment: thank you for your answer but still the same. Like I said It works well with my other application on the same device but doesn't work in this one. This is weird. I am looking for something that blocks or bypasses `UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(mailURL)` function but can not find the reason.

Answer (score 0):

For security reasons, Apple doesn't allow you to open URLs with arbitrary schemes, only those that you have registered to (so when they review your code they can figure out what applications you are checking for and reject you. Checking for mail is fine because everyone has that).

But Apple wouldn't allow you to check if my app is installed on a device.

Comment: Thanks but what should I do? Do you have any idea about this?